# Node js not resolving array of promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I'm trying to execute several async requests and trying to get the output using promises.

If I've multiple requests queued up the Q.all(promises).then () function doesn't seem to be working. For a single request the promises are all resolved. The sample code is here.

```
var request = require('request');
var Q = require('q');

var sites = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.example.com', 'http://www.yahoo.com'];
// var sites = ['http://www.google.com']

var promises = [];

for (site in sites) {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  promises.push(deferred.promise);
  options = {url: sites[site]};

  request(options, function (error, msg, body) {
    if (error) {
      deferred.reject();
    }

    deferred.resolve();
  });
}

Q.all(promises).then (function () {
  console.log('All Done');
});
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Surya

Comment: you'll need to provide more details- what exactly happens when you run the above code?

Comment: "*What am I doing wrong here?*" - Using (implicit) global `site` and  `options` variables. Using [`for in` enumeration on arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572). Also, the reason why it fails: your `deferred` will be overwritten by the subsequent calls, your callback is not a closure over it - it always tries to resolve the single, last `deferred`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I'd do in the scenario, this is the whole code:

```
var Q = require('q');
var request = Q.nfbind(require('request'));

var sites = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.example.com', 'http://www.yahoo.com'];
var requests = sites.map(request); 

Q.all(requests).then(function(results){
   console.log("All done") // you can access the results of the requests here
});
```

Now for the why:

- Always promisify at the lowest level possible, promisify the request itself and not the speicific requests. Prefer automatic promisification to manual promisification to not make silly errors.
- When working on collections - using `.map` is easier than manually iterating them since we're producing exactly one action per URL here.

This solution is also short and requires minimal nesting.

Comment: I realised my mistake to be one with closures. But I'm going to accept this answer as I found out another way of dealing with promises. Thanks

Comment: @Salman please elaborate - and feel free to ask another question. I have tested the code before posting it and it worked.

Comment: i dont know why cldnt i run may be something on my side so i have deleted my comment sory.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `for..in` to iterate over arrays.  What this actually does is set `site` to `0, 1, 2` and this just doesn't work very well.  Use some other form of iteration like a regular `for` loop, or `Array.prototype.forEach`

```
sites.forEach(function (site) {                                                 
  var deferred = Q.defer();                                                     
  promises.push(deferred.promise);                                               
  options = {url: site};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're changing the value of `deferred` on every tick of your `for` loop. So, the only promise which is actually resolved in your example is the last one.

To fix it you should store the value of `deferred` in some context. The easiest way to do so is to use [`Array.prototype.forEach()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of `for` loop:

```
sites.forEach(function (site){
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  var options = {url: sites[site]};
  promises.push(deferred.promise);

  request(options, function (error, msg, body) {
    if (error) {
      deferred.reject();
    }

    deferred.resolve();
  });
})
```

And you also missed `var` declaring `options` variable. In JavaScript it means declaration of a global variable (or module-wide variable in `node.js`).

Comment: Actually, using `map` is a much easier way, so you don't have to manually do `promises.push()`.

Comment: Ah.. closure. why didn't I think of it before.